# Cookies Laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

Есть domain1.com и sub.domain1.com

С domain1.com я посылаю ajax на sub.domain1.com для того, чтобы авторизоваться. Мне возвращается успешный ответ(указал Access-Control-Allow-* заголовки), но не устанавливаются cookies, в то время как если отправить этот же запрос с sub.domain1.com на sub.domain1.com cookies устанавливаются отлично и авторизация проходит успешно.

В .env

```
SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
```

В config/auth.php

```php
'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],
```

Как мне решить вопрос кроссдоменной авторизации в Laravel?

Comment: не знаю, то ли это, но в config/session.php есть детальные настройки куки - имя, домен и другое.

Comment: Можно в php.ini указать где сохранять куки. `session.cookie_domain = '.site.ru';`

Comment: Вам для успешного запроса нужно сначала слать OPTIONS и получать CORS заголовки чтобы понять можете ли вы вообще с ним общаться, а уже после этого слать свой запрос на авторизацию. По идее это делается автоматом при AJAX запросе, вам нужно добавить эти самые заголовки через middleware или header() в index.php файле на субдомене. Но по сути это два разных запроса и ответа - сначала OPTIONS, затем уже ваш запрос на авторизацию (GET или POST)